# Error: "no suitable method found for sort(List) Collections.sort" sorting in Java

Tags: java, sorting

I am trying to sort a List of coordinates. It gives me this error:

> error: no suitable method found for sort(List)
> Collections.sort(vertices);
> ^
> method Collections.<T#1>sort(List<T#1>) is not applicable
> (inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds
> equality constraints: Coordenada
> lower bounds: Comparable<? super T#1>)
> method Collections.<T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>) is not applicable
> (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
> (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
> where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
> T#1 extends Comparable<? super T#1> declared in method <T#1>sort(List<T#1>)
> T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>)
> 1 error

Here is my code:

```
 import java.util.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;
    
    public class PoligonoIrreg{
        List<Coordenada> vertices = new ArrayList<Coordenada>();
        public PoligonoIrreg(){
        }
        public void anadeVertice(Coordenada c1){
            vertices.add(c1);
        }
        public void ordenaVertices (){
            Collections.sort(vertices);
        }
        @Override
        public String toString( ) {
            vertices.forEach((vertice) -> {
                System.out.println(vertice);
            });
            return "Total de vertices: " + vertices.size();
        }
    }

    public class Coordenada {
    
        private double x, y, magnitud;
    
        public Coordenada(){
    
        }
    
        public Coordenada(double x, double y) {
    
            this.x = x;
    
            this.y = y;
    
            setMagnitud();
        }
    
        //Metodo getter de x
    
        public double abcisa( ) { return x; }
    
     
    
        //Metodo getter de y
    
        public double ordenada( ) { return y; }
    
        public double getMagnitud() {
            return magnitud;
        }
    
        public void setX(double x) {
            this.x = x;
            setMagnitud();
    
    
    
        }
    
        public void setY(double y) {
            this.y = y;
            setMagnitud();
    
    
        }
    
        //Sobreescritura del método de la superclase objeto para imprimir con System.out.println( )
    
        @Override
    
        public String toString( ) {
    
            return "Coordenada[" + x + "," + y + "] Magnitud:"+magnitud;
    
        }
    
        private void setMagnitud(){
            magnitud = Math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y));
        }
    
    }
```

Why do I get the error above?

Comment: You've given Java no indication of *how* you want the list sorted. Do you want it sorted by X coordinate? By magnitude? By all three fields in order lexicographically? By the average of X and Y? Java isn't going to take a wild guess.

Comment: Not what you asked, but using `Math.hypot` can be more accurate, in some circumstances, then using `Math.sqrt` with the sum of the squares.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Coordenada` class needs to implement the `Comparable` interface, otherwise, the `sort` method doesn't know how to sort the elements.  This means it will need to be declared like

```
public class Coordenada implements Comparable<Coordenada>
```

and contain a method

```
public int compareTo(Coordenada other)
```

whose return value is negative or positive depending on whether the current object should be sorted before or after the `other` object; or zero if the two objects are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Your class should implement Comparable interface and provide implementation to compareTo method.

You can also create a custom comparator to sort the list

Refer this link for more details: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparable-vs-comparator-in-java/